# Naming convention for enum extension class

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

Let's say I have an enum and an extension method for it:

```
public enum EFoo {
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}

public static class FooExt {
    public static void FooMethod(this EFoo foo) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What would be a better naming convention for the extension class:

- `FooExt` as shown above.
- `EFooExt`.
- Something else?

I know this is somewhat subjective and probably not the best question for SO, but I was wondering if there is an established convention that escaped me so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Enum should be named `Foo`, not `EFoo`.
C# does not encourage Hungarian Notation.

The extension class should then be named `FooExtensions`

Comment: +1 _"C# does not encourage Hungarian Notation"_ except for where it [does encourage it.](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/11/09/the-last-vestiges-of-hungarian-notation/) :)

Comment: I would also suggest making the extension class `public static partial class FooExtensions`, so that the same class can be used to collect extensions to the enum that are local to derived environments.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Does that have any specific advantage over just creating a separate extension class? Since the "derived environment" will likely have its own namespace, we can even "reuse" the same class name is desired.

Comment: The only advantage would be in code maintainability - but in the absence of any disadvantages I think that speaks for itself.